# Issues with simple Javascript/HTML script

Tags: javascript, operators

I keep getting an error no mater how I change my code. I have written it a few different ways but here is one of the ways.

The error I am receiving is 'Shipment charge is not found inside the div with id 'result''

UI Constraints : 
The file name should be index.html.
To compute shipping charge use (Total shipping charge= weight*cost).
Refer sample screenshot for detailed specifications.

[The code is suppose to look similar to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bl2U.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <style>
                #header {
                    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
                    margin : -8px -8px 0;
                    background-color: lightgrey;
                 }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="width:100%">
                <td style="width:20%">
                    <span>
                        <img align="left" src="logo.jpeg" width="120px" height="120px">
                    </span>
                </td>    
                <td style="width: 60%;">
                    <span>
                        <center>
                            <h1>DATAX Shipping Company</h1>
                        </center>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%; padding-bottom: 7%;padding-left:5%;">
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a>
                        <a href="#" id="login" style="padding-left:30px">Log in</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            <!-- fill code here -->
            <center>
<h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>
</center>
<form>
Total Product Weight <input type="text" id="weight" /><br>
Shipping cost (per kg) <input type="text" id="cost" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Compute" id="compute" />
</form>
The Total Shipment charge is <div id="result"></div>


<script>
    function multiplyBy()
{
        num1 = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("cost").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = num1 * num2;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you provide seems to be ok

Answer (score 5):

You are using an input field as your result field, not a div, as the error states.

Try changing your code like so:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = num1 * num2;
```

Also, you have a trailing `</p>` that needs to be removed, and a `<body>` tag too many.

### Edit

---

I took a closer look at your picture, and I suggest changing the `<input...>`to `<div...>` like so:

```
The Total Shipment charge is <div id="result"></div>
```

And then have the Javascript be:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerText = num1 * num2;
```

This is because it looks to me that you are given an assignment, with automatic testing, and that the test is looking for a `<div>` element, not an `<input>`.

### Edit#2

---

I copied your updated code to [CodePen.IO](https://codepen.io/canis1980/pen/YjeJaJ) and the code works as written, so the question then is, are you sure the site has gotten the updated code? Also, are they testing more than just the value inside the div? Are they testing the likeness to that picture? If so, some styling and possible refactoring of the structure might be needed.

### Edit#3

---

As per @Rainmx93 excellent comment, I've got this last thing to try:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerText = 'The Total Shipment charge is ' + (num1 * num2);
```

And changing the `div` from

```
The Total Shipment charge is <div id="result"></div>
```

To

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Also i see opening `body` tag inside body

Comment: ah I used a <p> previously and tried to change it and mustve missed that one. Still cant get it work for some reason though.

Comment: i see that it had the opening body also. oops. still having issues im not sure why.

Comment: @user10162549 edit your question and add the most recent code as an update below the original content. Also... Where does the error come from? Some automated test online or in a VM made by a school or something?

Comment: Let me update it. Its giving the exact same error. Its an automated test via the company I work for. I use UFT for work and they want me to also do these assignments in Java, JUnit, Cucumber, Selenium, Javascript, Groovy, Fitnesse, etc :|

Comment: @user10162549 if you have access to the code for the test, please share that as well, so we can see what exactly it is looking for.

Comment: it is on a website that has to be logged into

Comment: @user10162549 the automated test that is giving you the error. That is code written in the testsuite your company is using that is giving you the error...

Comment: @user10162549 ah, ok. And you dont have access to the code the tester has written to test your code? or is that service such that you pay for outsourced testers to write your tests for you?

Comment: Oh I dont have access to that... I wish. It is just terminal on the site.

Comment: I do not have access. I am a tester but they want us to learn other types of coding too

Comment: @user10162549 I see. I tested your code on codepen.io (see updated answer for link), and functionally it works. Structure might be an issue if the test is searching for your div with more than just the id.

Comment: @Canis i guess he needs result exactly like in picture, so you need to put text `The Total Shipment charge is` inside `div` and then append value to this div: `innerHTML += num1 * num2` but im not sure

Comment: thank you for your time and help. I will try to contact someone. Ive had smiliar issues to it not accepting Java code in the past that was correct.

Comment: it did not specify in the instructions for the structure just that it had the same id's. but I guess that could be something I can look into

Comment: @user10162549 Rainmx93 is probably correct. See my final update for a possible solution to make the working code pass. I've also edited the code in the CodePen.io to make it look visually more similar to the picture.

Comment: @user10162549 Just following up to see how you fared. Did my last edit help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your fault is just because you have an error in your html:

```
The Total Shipment charge is <input type= "text" id="result">



</p>
```

should be:

```
<p> The Total Shipment charge is:</p>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

you also have a 2 body tags, remove the second one.

Comment: ah I used a <p> previously and tried to change it and mustve missed that one. tried this and still cant get it work for some reason though.

Answer (score 1):

An `input` does not have `innerHTML`; it has a `value`.

Change

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
```

To

```
document.getElementById("result").value = num1 * num2;
```

Also, you have a few syntax errors in your HTML, including having two opening `body` tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <style>
                #header {
                    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
                    margin : -8px -8px 0;
                    background-color: lightgrey;
                 }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="width:100%">
                <td style="width:20%">
                    <span>
                        <img align="left" src="logo.jpeg" width="120px" height="120px">
                    </span>
                </td>    
                <td style="width: 60%;">
                    <span>
                        <center>
                            <h1>DATAX Shipping Company</h1>
                        </center>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%; padding-bottom: 7%;padding-left:5%;">
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a>
                        <a href="#" id="login" style="padding-left:30px">Log in</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            <!-- fill code here -->
            <center>
<h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>
</center>
<form>
Total Product Weight <input type="text" id="weight" /><br>
Shipping cost (per kg) <input type="text" id="cost" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Compute" id="compute" />
</form>
The Total Shipment charge is <input type= "text" id="result">




<p/>
<script>
    function multiplyBy()
{
        num1 = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("cost").value;
        document.getElementById("result").value = num1 * num2;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of using an `input` to display the results, you should use a `span`, in which case you could set its `innerHTML` or `textContent` to display the computed values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <style>
                    #header {
                        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
                        margin : -8px -8px 0;
                        background-color: lightgrey;
                     }
            </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr style="width:100%">
                    <td style="width:20%">
                        <span>
                            <img align="left" src="logo.jpeg" width="120px" height="120px">
                        </span>
                    </td>    
                    <td style="width: 60%;">
                        <span>
                            <center>
                                <h1>DATAX Shipping Company</h1>
                            </center>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 40%; padding-bottom: 7%;padding-left:5%;">
                        <span>
                            <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a>
                            <a href="#" id="login" style="padding-left:30px">Log in</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

                <!-- fill code here -->
                <center>
    <h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>
    </center>
    <form>
    Total Product Weight <input type="text" id="weight" /><br>
    Shipping cost (per kg) <input type="text" id="cost" /><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Compute" id="compute" />
    </form>
    <span id="result"></span>




    <p/>
    <script>
        function multiplyBy()
    {
            num1 = document.getElementById("weight").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("cost").value;
            document.getElementById("result").textContent = "The Total Shipment charge is "+num1 * num2;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("result").value= num1 * num2;
```

Since you are putting the result in an input field, it needs to have it's value changed. If you were using a `<p>` or other element, then that's when you would use innerText.

Comment: Actually you would be using innerText, as innerHTML is quite dangerous as it easily opens you to XSS.

Comment: ah I used a <p> previously and tried to change it and mustve missed that one. Still cant get it work for some reason though.